# clipping image to image using canvas

Tags: image, canvas, fabricjs, clip

Has anyone here have done clipping an image within an image? I've seen so far about clipping on the canvas but are all regular shapes(rectangle, circle, etc...). It would be nice if some have actually done it.

P.S. with fabric.js or just the regular canvas.

Answer (score 2):

**Sure, you can use compositing to draw a second image only where the first image exists:**

```
ctx.drawImage(image1,0,0);  // this creates the 'mask'
ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-in';
ctx.drawImage(image2,0,0);  // this image only draws inside the mask
```

**Illustration:** House image drawn first and second Grass image is drawn only where house pixels exist:

[image]

Example code an a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/r71d8d8b/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // put the paths to your images in imageURLs[]
    var imageURLs=[];  
    // push all your image urls!
    imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house100x100.png");
    imageURLs.push("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/mower_start.png");

    // the loaded images will be placed in images[]
    var imgs=[];
    var imagesOK=0;
    loadAllImages(start);

    function loadAllImages(callback){
        for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
            var img = new Image();
            imgs.push(img);
            img.onload = function(){ 
                imagesOK++; 
                if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                    callback();
                }
            };
            img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
            img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
            img.src = imageURLs[i];
        }      
    }

    function start(){

        // the imgs[] array now holds fully loaded images
        // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

        ctx.drawImage(imgs[0],50,50);
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-in';
        ctx.drawImage(imgs[1],0,0);

    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Second grass image is drawn only where<br>house pixels already existed<br>(Uses 'source-in' compositing)</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see it's possible. How about using fabric.js? how can I achieve something like this?

Comment: AFAIK, FabricJS does not do compositing. You can, however, always use an offscreen html5 canvas and use the results to create a FabricJS image using `fabric.Image.fromURL(canvas.toDataURL(),...`.

Comment: Do you mean make another canvas to do this sort of stuffs then pass in to fabricJS?

Comment: Yep! You can create an "in memory only" html5 canvas using `var canvas=createElement('canvas')` and then do your compositing on that html canvas using the code in my answer. Finally create an official FabricJS image with `fabric.Image.fromURL(canvas.toDataURL(),....`.  Cheers!

Comment: I can imagine now how this thing works. But if I do that I think I can't move the image in that layer mask, and every time I add another image to layer that mask should I repeat the process? 
Anyway, I found this http://jsfiddle.net/Kw4d3/ and tried it. The problem is it's using paths, which is svgs. The images are just pngs.

Comment: I don't know your design requirements, but yes, you would reuse the original in-memory canvas for your new mask and update the FabricJS image or create a new FabricJS image. Fairly straightforward and efficient.