# Creating a path from a PNG in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

- I have a PNG image with a transparent area.
- I have a photo.
- I am using FabricJS

I need to create a new image cropped to the transparent area of the PNG.

I understand I can use the clipTo(path) function to create the new image.

However, my problem is creating the path in the first place. How can I create a path from the transparent area of a PNG?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use clipPath but compositing. Not really using fabric so not a good dupe target https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752870/clipping-image-to-image-using-canvas But there are, I'm sure.

Answer (score 3):

*As strange as it may seem, I wasn't able to find a correct duplicate for this...*

---

You don't need to calculate a path from your bitmap. CanvasRenderingContext2d API offers some [compositing and blending options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation), which will allow you to work directly with bitmaps.

**fabricjs** also offers this option: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#globalCompositeOperation

```js
var c = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  imageSmoothingEnabled: false
});
fabric.Image.fromURL(
  'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4e90e48s5vtmfbd/aaa.png',
  function(image1) {
   fabric.Image.fromURL(
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg',
    function(image2) { // the one to be clipped
      c.add(image1);
      c.add(image2);
      c.renderAll();
   }, {
    globalCompositeOperation: 'source-in', // will be drawn only where pixels are already drawn
    top: -300,
    left: -400
  });

}, {
  width: 200,
  height: 200
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.18/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```